# I am trying to create a list within a list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to loop through all of my jira searches and contain them in a list of list

```
g_list= []
t_list= []
x=0

issues_in_project = jira.search_issues('labels=Reporting', expand='changelog', maxResults=False)

changelog = issue.changelog

for history in changelog.histories:
    for item in history.items:
        if item.field == 'status':
            t_list.append('Date:' + history.created + ' From:' + item.fromString + ' To:' + item.toString)
    g_list.append(t_list[0])
```

What i want is have all the status updates of a particular issue in one list as an element. Something like

```
[[Date:2019-03-27T10:08:45.997-0400 From:Open To:In Progress,
Date:2019-04-02T12:33:46.356-0400 From:In Progress To:Closed],
[Date:2019-03-27T10:08:45.997-0400 From:Open To:In Progress],
[Date:2019-03-27T10:08:45.997-0400 From:Open To:In Progress]]
```

Currently its giving me an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-42338ca03d78> in <module>
     11         if item.field == 'status':
     12             t_list.append('Date:' + history.created + ' From:' + item.fromString + ' To:' + item.toString)
---> 13     g_list.append(t_list[0])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Upon running only changelog- the output looks like this.

Code

```
for issue in issues_in_project:
    changelog = issue.changelog

for history in changelog.histories:
    for item in history.items:
        if item.field == 'status':
            print ('Date:' + history.created + ' From:' + item.fromString + ' To:' + item.toString)
```

Solution

```
Date:2019-03-27T10:08:45.997-0400 From:Open To:In Progress
Date:2019-04-02T12:33:46.356-0400 From:In Progress To:Closed
```

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: What is the current output of your code?

Comment: that just means no instance of `item.field` has value of `status`.

Comment: Could you show us what `changelog` looks like?

Comment: Please see my last two paragraphs

Answer (score 2):

It seems that t_list is empty. Are you sure, there is an item.field called 'status'?

Comment: Yes, I checked without appending to the list. It has elements for each jira ticket